# How to read a CSV file column wise using hadoop?

Tags: java, csv, hadoop

i am trying to read a csv file which does not contains coma separated values , these are columns for NASDAQ Stocks, i want to read a particular column, assume (3rd), do not know , how to get the column items. IS there any method to read Column wise data in hadoop? pls help here.

My CSV File Format is:

```
exchange    stock_symbol    date    stock_price_open    stock_price_high    stock_price_low stock_price_close   stock_volume    stock_price_adj_close
NASDAQ  ABXA    12/9/2009   2.55    2.77    2.5 2.67    158500  2.67
NASDAQ  ABXA    12/8/2009   2.71    2.74    2.52    2.55    131700  2.55
```

Edited Here:

Column A : exchange 
Column B : stock_symbol
Column C : date
Column D : stock_price_open
Column E : stock_price_high

and similarly.

These are Columns and not a comma separated values. i need to read this file as column wise.

Comment: If the file does not contain coma separated values, how can it be a CSV file at first place?

Comment: Apparently this is no CSV, but maybe a "TSV" (tab separated values)?

Comment: i have edited my question pleas there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to format excel sheet like, adding columns to a single text by using formula like:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,";",B2,";",C2,";"D2,";",E2,";",F2,";",G2,";",H2,";",I2)
```

and concatenate these columns by your required separator, i have used `;`, here. use what you want there to be.

Comment: yes, it may be indirect method of getting what i want to run in hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

In [Pig](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#load) it will look like this:

```
Q1 = LOAD 'file.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (exchange, stock_symbol, stock_date:double, stock_price_open, stock_price_high, stock_price_low, stock_price_close, stock_volume, stock_price_adj_close);
Q2 = FOREACH Q1 GENERATE stock_date;
DUMP C;
```